# Creating a Quick links box with border

Tags: html, css

I am having serious issues with making a quick links box. Please see my website http://www.orkoa.com/index4.html, you will notice I have played around with a few things and I am stuck. I was hoping you could help.

1) I am trying to add quick links and trying reduce the height of the top-sidebar and make the text perfectly center and align. I am having a very difficult time to achieve this.

2) In addition, I have added a gallery from w3c tutorials page, and added this within the “mainContent class”. Its working, but is this the correct way to go about this? If you do it independently, the gallery just sits at the bottom outside the “bottomcontent” class.

Any advice?

Comment: what is the second part of your question? it's difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

To center align the `h3` text in the to side bar, add this to your existing css

```
.top-sidebar h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

if you wish to cneter align all text in the side bar add this instead

```
.top-sidebar {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `aside` tag, you should make a `div` container and make it `float: right`

then you can place all the other sidebars inside that container, using more divs

you can then easily adjust their heights as all of them would be independent divs, although I'll suggest to avoid handling heights if you want to make it responsive. Better will be to use bootstrap.

As for making text center, you can use `text-align: center`. Whichever portion of the div needs to be in center, you can add this to the CSS of that portion.

Also, currently all the `aside` tags are having `float: left`, they should be `float: right`